# PHP function references

Tags: php, reference

I'm getting a fatal error trying to modify a variable that was passed by reference. I've looked at documentation on referencing passing in PHP functions and I can't figure out what I'm doing different. I found that if I remove the reference (ampersand) on t0 and t1 then I can assign it without a fatal error; however, I need to modify t0 and t1 for the tracing. I'm using PHP 5.5.9 if that matters.

The context of my problem is for a raytracer, and inside the sphere intersect method.
The function call looks like:

```
if($obj->intersect($ray, $t0, $t1)) { ... }
```

The intersect method looks like:

```
function intersect(Ray $ray, &$t0, &$t1) {
// if discrim is >= 0 go on
$discrim = $b * $b - (4.0 * $a * $c);
if($discrim >= 0) {
$t0 = (-1.0 * $b - sqrt($discrim)) / (2.0 * $a); // error ... }
```

The program runs if I change the function definition to:

```
function intersect(Ray $ray, $t0, $t1) { ...
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: The message is "The image "http://...." cannot be displayed because it contains errors".

Comment: This is the error displayed by the browser because it expects to get an image from the server but it receives content that is not an image. Open the URL of the image in your browser and use the "View Source" command of the browser to see the actual content received from the server. It probably contains a PHP error message.

Comment: I'm using GD to make a raytraced image. If I change the code above (remove the reference to t0 and t1), then the program will run (but the raytracer won't work because I need the value of t0 outside the intersect method). I suppose I could use global variables, but I really want to know why the reference is causing the fatal error. I've made similar code in C++ and it runs fine.

Comment: I think the references are not guilty for a fatal error on that line but without the error message produced by PHP I cannot tell what is wrong. Can you post the error message or an URL where the script output can be viewed?

Comment: Hmm, when I remove all the GD methods and use var_dump(debug_backtrace()), I can see the issue is right around the intersect method. Here's the part where it shows the intersect params: "["direction":"Ray":private]=> NULL } [1]=> &bool(false) [2]=> &bool(false) } } " . What's weird is the t0 and t1 references are being shown as booleans. That might be my issue? Because I'm trying to assign them float values.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to references is to make the function return the values of `$t0` and `$t1`:

```
// Modify the function to return the new values of $t0 and $t1
function intersect(Ray $ray, $t0, $t1)
{
    // Function code here, including the modification of $t0 and $t1

    // $result is the value previously returned by function (boolean, I guess)
    return array($result, $t0, $t1);
}


// Modify the code that calls the function to match its new behaviour
list($res, $t0, $t1) = $obj->intersect($ray, $t0, $t1);
if ($res) { ... }
```

If the function does not use the initial values of parameters `$t0` and `$t1` then they can be removed from the parameters list.